# Retrofit, POST request for upload image and string value

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

me and my team is trying to use retrofit. i want to upload an image with some string value using POST request. i keep getting the eror "filename" is undefined. is this right ?

```
private void uploadMultipart(File file) {
    final String kodedokter = "D021422";
    final String bulan = "12";
    final String tahun = "2016";
    RequestBody photoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part photoPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sign",
            file.getName(), photoBody );
    RequestBody kodedokter1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("kode_dokter"), kodedokter);
    RequestBody bulan1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("bulan"), bulan);
    RequestBody tahun1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("tahun"), tahun);
    uploadService = new UploadService();
    uploadService.uploadPhotoMultipart(kodedokter1,bulan1,tahun1, photoPart, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            BaseResponse baseResponse = (BaseResponse) response.body();

            if(baseResponse != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, baseResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
private void sendSinglePhoto(String location, String longitude, String latitude, File singleImage) {
    Constant.showProgressDialog(SinglePhotoActivity.this);

    RequestBody Location = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), location);
    RequestBody Longitude = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), longitude);
    RequestBody Latitude = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), latitude);

    RequestBody ProfileImage;
    MultipartBody.Part body;
    if (singleImage != null) {
        ProfileImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), singleImage);
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("single_image", singleImageFile.getName(), ProfileImage);
    } else {
        ProfileImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "");
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("single_image", "", ProfileImage);
    }

    uploadSinglePhoto(this, Location, Longitude, Latitude, body);
}


public void uploadSinglePhoto(final NetworkResponseListener listener, RequestBody location, RequestBody longitude, RequestBody latitude, MultipartBody.Part singleImage) {

    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestClient.ROOT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestClient.NetworkCall networkCall = retrofit.create(RestClient.NetworkCall.class);


    Call<UploadPhotoResponse> response = networkCall.uploadSinglePhoto(Prefs.getAuth(App.getContext()), location, longitude, latitude, singleImage);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<UploadPhotoResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadPhotoResponse> call, Response<UploadPhotoResponse> response) {
            if (response.code() == Constant.SUCCESS_STATUS) {
               "Your Success Code should be here"
            } else {
               "Your Success Code should be here"
           }
     }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadPhotoResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}


  @Multipart
    @POST("your URL")
    Call<UploadPhotoResponse> uploadSinglePhoto(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Part("location") RequestBody location, @Part("longitude") RequestBody longitude, @Part("latitude") RequestBody latitude, @Part MultipartBody.Part singleImage);
```

Comment: what the meaning of "single_image" in this block
`if (singleImage != null) {
        ProfileImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), singleImage);
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("single_image", singleImageFile.getName(), ProfileImage);
    } else {
        ProfileImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "");
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("single_image", "", ProfileImage);
    }`

Comment: "single_image" is your parameter name